# How can I get the span text with incremental id using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm sorry guys I've changed my code to this:

```
<table border="1">
<?php
$a = array('apple','banana','grapes','pineapple');
for ($x=0;$x<=3;$x++)
{
?>
    <tr>
        <td><div class='fruit' ><?php echo $a[$x]; ?></div></td>
        <td><a href='#' class='viewbutton'>View</a></td>
    </tr>
<?php
}
?>    
</table>
```

Now my problem is how can I get the text inside the `<div>`? I've tried `$(".viewbutton").click(function() { alert ( $('#div_debit').text()  ); });` This will return only the first value. How can I get the succeeding values in the array? is it using id?

Comment: Why can't you use class selectors?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there's no CSS or jQuery-specific selector to match for all numeric values (like `[0-9]` or  `\d` in regexes); correct me, if I'm wrong!

But: as you give each `<span>` the class "fruit", you can just access them with `span.fruit`. This will return an array, which you can iterate over with [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/). `this` will be set to the current item within that function, so you can check for the desired ID.

```
$('.fruit').each(function(){
    // this.id will be your numeric ID of the current item
});
```

Also, if your elements are numbered continuously (e.g. 1, 2, 3, and not 2, 1, 3), you can use the [`:nth-child`-pseudo-selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#nth-child-pseudo) to access one of the `<span>`s.

If all of this doesn't work for you; e.g. if you need to use the class `.fruit` somewhere else too, the last option I could think of is that you iterate manually over the elements in JavaScript.

```
for( var x = 0; x <= 3; x++ ) {
    var e = $('#'+x);
    // Do something with the element; or add it to an array of all the elements
}
```

**Edit:** If you don't know how many items there will be in the page, but you want to match for every numeric ID, you can use the following.

```
$('*').each(function(){
    if( this.id.match(/\d+/) ) {
        // do something with an element which has a numeric ID
    }
});
```

of course, its preferrable to use the above example, if you know how many items there will be, because it's probably faster.

Comment: Sir I just want to get the text value, for example. <span class='fruit' id='1'>banana</span> <span class='fruit' id='2'>apple</span> . How can I get the "banana" or "apple" text if the code has incremental id but has the same class using jQuery? Thank you.

Comment: Try `innerHTML`; or jQuery's `.text()` on `$(this)` within the function of the first example in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are, probably, make it wrong. Don't use id as a number like this, prefer put at least a prefix on it.

You can use $('span.fruit#1').text() to get the first text span. If you don't put a id, you can use $('span.fruit:nth-child(1)').text().